# Add manually something to old in Laravel 6.5

Tags: php, laravel, session, input, laravel-6

i'm working on a Laravel project, and i have a page where each specific div is shown when `old('tab_name')` is equals to something (just a unique key for each tab)... now on my controller i have to redirect to that route with

```php
return redirect()->to(route('name of that route'));
```

and i want that a specific div to be shown, so i need to put to the old input manually the 'key' of that div... is there any way? Otherwise i'll use `Session::flash()` but it's not that clean in my opinion

Comment: i feel like a regular flash var is more correct as this isn't actually user input ... the only difference between is `old('tab_name')` and `session('tab_name')`

Comment: @lagbox yes, but i already have 2 condition to fire that div to be open, adding another won't be that great... in other case, i'll totally agree with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
redirect()->route('route name here')->withInput(['tab_name' => '...']);
```